# Notion of functions on Elliptic curves over scheme and writing them as power series.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am trying to understand a statement in Andrew Snowden's [Notes](https://www.mit.edu/%7ENivenT/assets/pdf//UMich_679_Notes.pdf) regarding the representability of the functor $F_{\Gamma(3)}$ (Section 14.1).

Here, $F_{\Gamma(N)}(S)= \{isom \; classes \; of \; (E,(P,Q)) \; over \; S\}.$
 
In Section 14.1, the notes state:

" Riemann-Roch says we can pick a function $x$ on E w/ a pole of order 2 along the zero section, and
no other poles. This will be unique upto $x \mapsto ax+b$. "

My question(1):
What is the notion of a "function on E having a pole of order 2 along the zero section"?

Additionally:
While reading Hida's book "Geometric modular forms and elliptic curves" (section 2.2.5), I encountered a similar concept where x is expressed as a power series.

[image]

Specific question(2):
How can we write x as a power series and why does it have a pole of order 2?

Context:
I have read the previous section in Hida's book (section 2.2.4) where he discusses the power series expansion of $\omega \in \Gamma(E, \underline{\omega}_{E/S})$, but I am unsure how this relates to writing x as a power series.